# Draw an arrow pattern using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a recursive function (we'll call it `arrow(n)`) which draws an arrow that works like this:

```
arrow(4)
```

Printed output :

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

where `arrow` can only take one parameter like shown above.

Is it possible only by using one parameter with recursion? I'm curious because it was a test question and I can't find any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, even when recursing, you'll need two variables (one to keep track of the current count, and another to keep track of the size).

You can get cute and use an inner function.

```
def arrow(n):
   def _arrow(k, n):
       print('*' * (n - k + 1))
       if k > 1:
           _arrow(k - 1, n)
           print('*' * (n - k + 1))
   _arrow(n, n)
```

```
arrow(4)
# *
# **
# ***
# ****
# ***
# **
# *
```

It's essentially the more unreadable equivalent of loops, but hey, that's the nature of exam questions.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion is in the helper functions, rather than `arrow`, but it's still single-parameter recursion in each case.

```
def arrow_top(n):
    if n > 0:
        arrow_top(n-1)
        print('*' * n)

def arrow_bot(n):
    if n > 0:
        print('*' * n)
        arrow_bot(n-1)

def arrow(n):
    arrow_top(n)
    arrow_bot(n-1)

arrow(4)
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score -1):

This works by setting a global to remember where to iterate to:

```
def arrow(n):
    # remember max, but only once
    global top
    try:
        top
    except NameError:
        top = n
        n = 1

    if n < top:
        print(n * '*')
        arrow(n + 1)
        print(n * '*')
    elif n == top:
        print(n * '*')

arrow(4)
```